# ios app build for version 5.0.1uploaded to app store can be run on ios 5.1?

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval

I did build app for ios 5.0.1 using xcode 4.2 and uploaded it on apple store. They rejected my app due to crash issue occurs when they install and run on ios 5.1.

Could you please let me know if we build an app for ios 5.0.1 will not be run on ios5.1 iphone device.

What will be the way so I can approved my app at apple store that is build for ios 5.0.1.

But two days ago they approved another app that is build for ios 5.0.1.

Should I query to apple store.

Please reply me thank a lot for time frame given to my ques.

Answer (score 0):

The app can run in iOS 5.1, the thing is that you dont know how that app is going to work on 5.1, so probably you are using something that is allowed in 5.0.1, and in 5.1 is crashing.

Your only option now, is to download the 5.1 on your xCode and check what is going on.

Comment: @Dear Antonio I appreciate your valuable time to ans. I did test my ios5.0.1 build app on ios 5.0.1 device Several times it's not crashing. my deployment target is ios 3.0. It is recommended that we have to upload ios app must be supportable for iPad with seperate .xib in project without auto-resizing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Apple will approve apps that are built using the 5.0 SDK, though probably not anything earlier. They pretty much always test using the latest version of the OS so you should absolutely test with it before submitting. I'd venture that there's no reason not to *develop* with the latest too.

The changes between 5.0 and 5.1 are not huge so, chances are, you do have a bug. Apple normally send crash reports when they reject for these reasons.

Comment: The deployment target is different. The SDK is what you build your app with. The deployment target is a flag saying which is the oldest version of the OS that's supported.

Comment: @Dear Stephen Many thanks to you, I will check out the crash report.

Comment: Stackoverflow is very good place to get quickly technical help. I am very happy with you guys.